# Sum List of BigDecimal

Tags: java, list, collections, java-7

I am working on a project with Spring and Maven and Java 7.

I have a list with bigdecimal and have to sum up all the elements in the list. i know using for loop we can to as below,

```
List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
list.add(new BigDecimal(10.333));
list.add(new BigDecimal(14.333));
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
for (BigDecimal b : list) {
     result = result.add(b);
}
```

Is there a better way to do? using google gauva FluentIterable or apache ArrayUtils/StatUtils?

Comment: @kkkkk Yes. That is BigDecimal.add(). I want to iterate list and add. So i want to make something as the api FluentIterable does

Comment: I think your solution is concise and clean. Why would you change it? Maybe you should go for Java 8 and its `Stream API`.

Comment: One small improvement: `BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;`. Otherwise, your code is good.

Comment: @Flown yes i am aware of Stream in java 8. But i cannot migrate my application to java 8 now. As i said i want to use some think like FluentIterable

Comment: When using constructors on String `list.add(new BigDecimal(`"10.333"));` BigDecimal will know the precision of 3, and the sum will be correct. Momentarily you import approximation errors of doubles into the sum. To the question: there is no better way, as BigDecimal is immutable. Java 8 would allow parallel stream adding.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to do it with only Java 8 and streams:

```
List<BigDecimal> list = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(10.333), //
   new BigDecimal(14.333));
BigDecimal result = list.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use Java 8 lambdas or Groovy closures, in which case you could write a one-liner to replace your four lines, the code you have is thoroughly clear. Using a library-based iteration tool will almost certainly make the code more complicated and *will* certainly make it slower. You made it about as simple as it gets; it's fine.

Comment: Exactly. Well, replacing the initial value `new BigDecimal(0)` with [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO), but that’s it. Nothing more to improve…

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the extra third-party library dependency, then there is a solution for this problem in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
List<BigDecimal> list =
    Lists.mutable.with(
        new BigDecimal("10.333"),
        new BigDecimal("14.333"));

Assert.assertEquals(
    new BigDecimal("24.666"),
    Iterate.sumOfBigDecimal(list, Functions.getPassThru()));
```

Since you have a list of BigDecimal already, the function that is applied to each just passes the value through.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections